# PyCharm: How to use one project as dependency of another?

Tags: pycharm, pythonpath

In PyCharm I have one project that makes calls to another project's modules.

For example let's say we have two projects abc and xyz. Within project abc we have a module abc.mod_a with function f1(), and within project xyz we have a module xyz.mod_b with function f2().

abc.mod_a.py:

```
import xyz.mod_b
def f1():
    xyz.mod_b.f2()
```

xyz.mod_b.py:

```
def f2():
    print("something was done")
```

I've done the following to make this possible:

I have added xyz as a project dependency for project abc:
Settings->Project->Project Dependencies

I have added the path to xyz's primary directory to the PYTHONPATH for the interpreter used for project abc:
Settings->Project->Project Interpreter->Show All->Interpreter Paths->Add Path

When I run code that uses abc.mod_a.py I get a module not found error on the initial import xyz statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way is to work on the abc project and open the xyz project. You get the dialog below.

[image]

This will open the xyz inside of your abc project. It will handle all of the dependencies for you.

Another alternative is to install your xyz python library in development mode.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs

```
pip install -e ../path_to/xyz
```

This creates a link in your python's site-packages directory which points to your xyz directory. When you call `import xyz.mod_b` it will look in the proper directory.

Comment: Thank you @justengel. I think I did what you first propose above in that I added xyz as a project after already having abc opened as a project in PyCharm. Your second suggestion is interesting, is this something that's easy to back out (I've had difficulty getting pip uninstall to completely clean up an installed package before)? The reason I ask is because I have package xyz installed in my interpreter's environment already and what I'm doing now is attempting to replace it temporarily with a source version that I may edit for a git PR, but I want to develop it first within PyCharm...

Comment: ...and once that's complete I don't want to have hosed the previous installation of xyz in the interpreter. Will `pip uninstall -e ../path_to/xyz` properly clean up and leave the interpreter back in its original state, i.e. with the original version of xyz still installed in the virtual environment (site-packages) of the interpreter? It's probably not too difficult for me to reinstall it if it gets hosed, but I'm trying to be careful to avoid tangling anything up if I can avoid it, as I've found this sort of thing to be tricky, although I guess this is how you learn.

Comment: BTW if I don't add xyz as a project dependency or on the PYTHONPATH for project abc's interpreter then the package is found as expected since it's been installed into the Anaconda virtual environment. I'm trying this other approach because I don't want to edit the code installed in site-packages, that seems like asking for trouble, and instead I want to edit the source for xyz in a separate location, i.e. the separate project xyz.

Comment: You would uninstall with `pip uninstall xyz`. I have not had a problem with pip uninstall before. I think it is just creating a .egg folder in site-packages which links to your directory. You aren't editing the code in site-packages.

I have not had an issue with PyCharm not using my dependent project. Make sure your package has an `__init__.py` file. You can also right click and exclude directories that have the same name or you can mark a parent directory as a sources root.

Comment: For editable install, pycharm inspections didn't work (although running it did). 

So I used the first option, too, -- ' add to currently opened projects'. However that wasn't enough. I had to tweak this in settings: Project -> Project Dependencies -> set which project depends on which. By default it was set incorrectly (the other way around).